# Excluding src/main/resources files in JAR plugin for Web module

Tags: maven, struts2, jar, war, pom.xml

Hi I have a maven project with multiple modules. Out of 4 modules, 2 are web. Here is the structure.

```
MyProject
   |
   |__ api
   |
   |__ commons
   |
   |__ web_child
   |
   |__ web_main
```

**web_main** module is the main one and it can include **web_child** module also.

web_child module structure is

```
 web_child
     |
     |__ src/main/java //java action classes and all
     |__ src/main/resources
     |    |__ struts-default.xml
     |
     |__ WEB-INF
          |__ JSP Pages
```

web_main module structure is

```
 web_main
     |
     |__ src/main/java //java action classes and all
     |__ src/main/resources
     |    |__ struts.xml
     |
     |__ WEB-INF
          |__ JSP Pages
```

Both modules are **war**.

**web-main** depends on all the modules. and **web-child** depends on first two (api & commons) modules.

In struts.xml I am including the **struts-default.xml**.

In **web-child** module in **pom.xml** I am using WAR plugin and JAR plugin. and **web-child** module is working fine.
JAR plugin is used to create JAR of the module. But the problem is, I do not want to include the **`src/main/resources`** i the JAR.

Here is my JAR plugin in  `web-child` module pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version> 
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>jar</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
              <classifier>core</classifier>
               <excludes>
                  <exclude>src/main/resources</exclude>
                </excludes>
           </configuration>
           </execution>
    </executions>                        
    </plugin>
```

This creates JAR. This JAR I am adding as dependency in `web-main` module.

**web-main pom.xml dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.parent.artifactId}-child</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    <classifier>core</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>
    <artifactId>${project.parent.artifactId}-child</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

The first gets the JAR and second gets the war. So all the main resources from web-child will come in WEB-INF classes. And it is conflicting with files in WEB-INF/lib/web-child.jar! files.

So how can I remove the src/main/resources from JAR and get that JAR in main-web?

**NOTE**: I have tried the following inside WAR plugin

```
<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
<classesClassifier>core</classesClassifier>
<packagingExcludes>src/main/resources</packagingExcludes>
```

Comment: Help me understand why both web-child war and jar are required in web-main please?

Comment: The web-main needs to have the JSP pages of web-child as well as its action classes.

Comment: Makes sense.  Why is the war not sufficient?  Have you looked at [war overlays?](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html)

Comment: War copies the JSP pages and main resources. JAR has classes and main/resources . So both in main web, main resources will be available in two places and its conflicting